# Rotating symbols in exponents

Tags: rotating

So I saw another post on here explaining how to rotate a symbol by some degree, the solution they gave was
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{ \equiv}, but this seems to mess with the size and placement of the symbol when it is put into an exponent. Is there a way to fix its size and center to be congruent to the original symbol?

Comment: Try with `\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\scriptstyle\equiv$}`...

Comment: @Werner Absolutely perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Eons ago I tinkered a `\mathrotate` macro which can be used in math mode and scales according to the math style. (Actually I thought I'd already posted it but I can't find it...)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}% for \binrel@

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mathrotate}[3][]{\binrel@{#3}\binrel@@{\mathpalette{\math@rotate{#1}{#2}}{#3}}}
\newcommand*{\math@rotate}[4]{% #1=options, #2=angle, #3=math style, #4=symbol
   \if\relax\detokenize\expandafter{\@gobble#1?}\relax
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
   \else
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
   \fi
   {\rotatebox}{\rotatebox[#1]}{#2}{\m@th$#3#4$}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\mathrotate{90}{\equiv} a^{\mathrotate{90}{\equiv}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The test for an empty optional argument is necessary because `\rotatebox` and `\rotatebox[]` do *not* yield the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `\scalerel*` command from the `scalerel` package to make the resizing automatic:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{scalerel}

\newcommand{\requiv}{\scalerel*{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\equiv$}}{X}}

\begin{document}

\[
X\requiv^{\requiv^{\requiv}}
\]

\end{document}
```